# Directory.CreateDirectory does not work after building Unity project

Tags: unity-game-engine

As I described in the tittle, creating a new directory with Directory.CreateDirectory does not work after I build my Unity project. Strangely, it works just fine when I launch it from the editor.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System;
using System.IO;

public class FileTool : MonoBehaviour
{
    public string folderName = "name";
    public string path = Environment.CurrentDirectory;
    public string fullPath;

    public void CreateFolder()
    {
        fullPath = Path.Combine(path, folderName);
        Debug.Log(fullPath);
        if (!Directory.Exists(fullPath))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(fullPath);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What error does the create directory fail with then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I wasn't able to make it automatic, I managed to make it work by having the user input the name and location.

Comment: Your answer could be improved by providing an example of the solution and how it solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that `Environment.CurrentDirectory` will return something adequate in the build. Even if so, I highly doubt that you will have write permission to this location.

Use [`Application.persistentDataPath`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-persistentDataPath.html) instead to create files in the build and store them between sessions.

Comment: This would probably work, but I need a folder that the users could easily access, so a folder in the same folder as the exe, or at least in a folder close to it would be the most ideal.

Comment: @Qroo try Application.dataPath, on Win/Linux player: <path to executablename_Data folder> (note that most Linux installations will be case-sensitive!)